# best practice with CRUD system and JOIN queries in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter to develop my app and I put together a very basic CRUD system (literally just create, retrieve, update & delete functions in my models) based on tutorial I found years ago (I forgot the URL). As I'm developing my app I realize I'm having to call the retrieve function of multiple models to get the data I need for a view (i.e., get_product, get_category, get_buyer, etc.). I understand using a JOIN query is best for grabbing data from multiple tables, but in CodeIgniter with a CRUD model system where should JOIN queries live (controller, in the respective primary model or a separate model)?

Answer (score 0):

You should handle queries in model section.
This is a example join query in codeigniter using [Active Records](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html).

```
$this->db->join();

Permits you to write the JOIN portion of your query:

$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('blogs');
$this->db->join('comments', 'comments.id = blogs.id');

$query = $this->db->get();

// Produces: 
// SELECT * FROM blogs
// JOIN comments ON comments.id = blogs.id
Multiple function calls can be made if you need several joins in one query.
```

If you need a specific type of JOIN you can specify it via the third parameter of the function. Options are: left, right, outer, inner, left outer, and right outer.

```
$this->db->join('comments', 'comments.id = blogs.id', 'left');

// Produces: LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.id = blogs.id
```

Comment: Well, I'm familiar with performing JOINs with Active Records, but I'm specifically wondering about which model to place them in when they span various tables (and each table has its own model).

Comment: You can write join query in any model. If you want to write join with  tables from three models means, you can write join query in any of  three model.

Comment: Nevermind. I'm just going to modify my basic retrieve models to accept extra arguments that'll generate complex JOIN queries. Thanks everyone